# Autohotkey & VirtualBox no longer get global hotkeys - How to track culprit?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys

Windows-7 system, up to date with patches.

As of Monday, after a first-thing-in-the-morning update to VirtualBox, I found that none of my AutoHotKey scripts are working (I had scripts on Win-G, Win-Shift-G, and I had it set to keep numlock on always).

I also found that Alt-tab is no longer being passed to VirtualBox (Previously, when my mouse was in the VM, and I was typing, Alt-Tab would be passed to the VM. Now it's being passed only to Windows).

At the same time, I've noticed that Win-G now brings up Chrome and does a google search for whatever is on the clipboard.

Note that I did check the chrome extensions page, and none of my installed extensions have global hotkeys.

How do I prove which app is the culprit here? Is there any way to lock a given App out of getting global hotkeys (I don't need Chrome to have any, so if I could just turn off it's ability to get them, that would let me prove it's the culprit).

I would prefer to NOT remove Chrome, but if that's the only way to prove it's the culprit, then so be it.

Update: I removed both Chrome and VirtualBox. Autohotkey still doesn't work, and Win-G still gets me a search in the default browser. So is this some kind of new Windows behavior?

Update: And a couple of reboots later (normal course of events), everything has decided to work again.

I would very much like to know a technique for tracing what is grabbing a given global shortcut, so that I can hunt this problem next time it occurs.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently Windows logo key+G  is "Cycle through (desktop) gadgets". It does nothing here though on my Windows 7 - probably because I don't have any gadgets on my desktop. Do you have an gadgets on your desktop?

Comment: Nope, no gadgets. And all of this did work once upon a time. Something's gone and changed behavior, and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what it is.